# CSS - center search form

Tags: css, forms, margin

How can I center [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQrrgJ) search field, by adding to the id **#search**?
I have tried to add both `margin: 0 auto;` and `left: 50%;` to **#search**, but neither works.

Comment: One solution - `display: block; width: 290px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto`

Comment: Another solution might be using display: flex by adding this: `display: flex;
  justify-content: center;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good read... [How To Center Anything With CSS](https://codemyviews.com/blog/how-to-center-anything-with-css)

In your case just add `width:265px;margin:auto` and remove `display:inline-block` in `#search`.

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojbbmL

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add a container for search and using `text-align: center`:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

/* ---------- GENERAL ---------- */

body {
  background: #61646d;
  color: #000;
  font: 14px/1.5em"Open Sans", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
input {
  border: none;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
/* ---------- SEARCH ---------- */

#search {
  background: #42454e;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px;
}
#search input {
  float: left;
}
#search input[type="search"],
#search input[type="submit"] {
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#search input[type="search"] {
  background: #fff;
  color: #42454e;
  min-width: 184px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
}
#search input[type="submit"] {
  background: #1bba9a;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 7px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}
#search input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #189e83;
}
#search input[type="search"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #42454e;
}
#search input[type="search"]:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #42454e;
}
#search input[type="search"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #42454e;
}
.searchCont {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Search</title>

  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
  <div class="searchCont">
    <div id="search">

      <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="GET">

        <fieldset class="clearfix">

          <input type="search" name="search" value="What are you looking for?" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='What are you looking for?'" onFocus="if(this.value=='What are you looking for?')this.value='' ">
          <!-- JS because of IE support; better: placeholder="What are you looking for?" -->
          <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button">

        </fieldset>

      </form>

    </div>
    <!-- end search -->
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I believe that the OP only wants to add additional styles to the **#search** element - _"...by adding to the id #search"_

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `<div id="container">` before `<div id="search">` , like below:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="search">
    <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="GET">
      // same line of codes
   </form>
  </div> <!-- end search -->
</div> <!-- end container -->
```

And just add in css file the below code:

**CSS:**

```
#container{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**Working code snippets:**

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

/* ---------- GENERAL ---------- */

body {
  background: #61646d;
  color: #000;
  font: 14px/1.5em"Open Sans", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
input {
  border: none;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
/* ---------- SEARCH ---------- */

#search {
  background: #42454e;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#search input {
  float: left;
}
#search input[type="search"],
#search input[type="submit"] {
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#search input[type="search"] {
  background: #fff;
  color: #42454e;
  min-width: 184px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
}
#search input[type="submit"] {
  background: #1bba9a;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 7px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}
#search input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #189e83;
}
#search input[type="search"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #42454e;
}
#search input[type="search"]:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #42454e;
}
#search input[type="search"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #42454e;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Search</title>

  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="search">

      <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="GET">

        <fieldset class="clearfix">

          <input type="search" name="search" value="What are you looking for?" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='What are you looking for?'" onFocus="if(this.value=='What are you looking for?')this.value='' ">
          <!-- JS because of IE support; better: placeholder="What are you looking for?" -->
          <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button">

        </fieldset>

      </form>

    </div>
    <!-- end search -->
  </div>
  <!-- end container -->

</body>

</html>
```